# Adjust layout of metaprop output

Tags: r

I use the code below to create the plot, but the "test for different subgroups differences " - the very bottom line of result is overlapped with label of x-axis. Can anyone help to point out how to update the code to avoid this issue? thanks!

```
myresult3 <- metaprop(n, N, data = result4, studlab = paste(race_ehr), 
                      subgroup = result4$incentiveB, method = "inverse")


forest(myresult3, 
       fixed=F, 
       random=T, 
       pooled.events = T, 
       overall = T, prediction = T, 
       xlab = "Proportion of 'complete=1'", 
       smlab="p̂ [95%CI]", 
       leftlabs = c("Race", "n", "N"),
        heterglabel = 5.5)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't have your data, but it's very easy to make a reproducible example here:

```r
library(meta)

mod <- metaprop(c(48, 37, 38, 45, 40), rep(50, 5), method = "inverse",
                subgroup = c("a", "a", "b", "b", "b"))

forest(mod, random = TRUE, prediction = TRUE, overall = TRUE)
```

[image]

To avoid lines clashing, increase the line spacing using the `spacing` argument:

```r
forest(mod, random = TRUE, prediction = TRUE, overall = TRUE, spacing = 1.8)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can I ask one more question based on that? When I use spacing=, it adjusts all lines in the plots, what if I just want to increase the space for the last three statistical output lines? Thanks!

Comment: I don't think that's possible in this function @Rstudyer - I did look around the various options, but I couldn't find anything that would permit per-line spacing without actually hacking the function.